# how to nested data from inside a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

```
const data = [{
  "detectedLanguage": {
    "language": "hi",
    "score": 1
  },
  "translations": [{
    "text": "long steff",
    "to": "en"
  }]
}]
```

How do I console.log only the `translation.text` field?

I tried `console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data.translation.text)` but that gives me the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
console.log(data[0].translations[0].text)
```

No need to use `Json.stringify`, because `data[0].translations[0].text` is not a Json, it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You created arrays and am missing the index and the "s" in translation**s**:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data[0].translations[0].text))
```

I also don't know why you're referencing it as `res.data`